# Some print jobs get stuck in queue when attempting to print from Google Docs or email

Tags: windows, printing, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11 and having a printer issue.  I can print a test sheet from the printer settings as well as from Word and from Adobe Reader.

However, when I try to print from Google Docs or email or any other browser based page the job spools to the print queue but never prints.

Comment: Printing from chrome has been an issue for many years, google provides no solution as I can find. I have the same issue for years.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the print queue:

```
Right-click “Command Prompt” and select “Run as administrator“. 
Type net stop spooler then press “Enter“. 
Type del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers\* /Q then press “Enter“. 
Type net start spooler then press “Enter“. 
The print queue on your Windows should now be cleared.
```

Restart the computer and test.

If you experience repeated issues with the printer, reinstall the printer:

```
Delete the Print Queue as above.
Restart.
Remove the Printer (Devices and Printers)
Uninstall the Printer.
Restart.
Install the printer.
```

After both the major steps above, and assuming your machine to be working correctly otherwise, printing should be repaired.